# C# Code Editor which does not require Admin Privileges to Install

Tags: c#, ide

I am a Support Engineer interested in learning Programming. I have borrowed a few books from Library to learn C#, however, my office PC does not have admin privileges. Is there any code editor for C# which provides syntax highlighting but does not require admin privileges to install.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Sharp Develop Portable 0.9](http://portableapps.com/node/6010)

> Sharp develop is an open source integrated development environment for several .NET programming languages (C#, VB.NET, Boo).
>
> Since Sharpdevelop itself is completely written in C# it needs the .NET Framework 2.0 on the host mashine to run. I check for the presence of this component at each launch of the portable app. If it´s not found, the Portable wrapper tries to downlad and install it. (Thanx to the developers of the NSISDotnet plugin!) 
>   Of course this is only possible if the user has administration rights. So this is some kind of limitation, but since the .NET Framework is already installed in Windows Vista and more and more programs are depending on this framework, it´s distribution is growing and growing.
>
> The portable wrapper application copies all setting files forth and back so there is a slight delay before the start of the application.
>
> The complete package consumes about 36MB on your portable device, I just deleted the samples folder of the original distribution to safe some space.
>   I includes a manifest file in the wrapper application, so there shouldn´t be UAC warnings when starting it.

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable) is a very handy editor.  It supports many syntax highlighting including C#.  Portable version takes only ~8Mb.

Answer (score 1):

i have to answer always with [vim](http://www.vim.org). works *everywhere*.

for a *portable* version of vim for windows: just go [here](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) and grab the runtime.zip and the gvim73.zip. put them somewhere. end of story. or go over to [portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/gvim_portable) and grab their gvim package.